# Fatal Error: 8 (Device Error) Boot on ESXI

Tags: vmware, esxi

We got one server which runs a vmware esxi and also holds two other VMs. When we try to reboot the desktop, we encounter this error below:

[image]

I tried to do another reboot to enter the BIOS setup. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the boot sequence but below is the current set-up:

[image]

I'm really not a infra or systems admin person and appreciate any resolutions to resolve the problem. I previously only access the server through the vSphere client. Apologies if my jargons aren't correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, first tried the recovery (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) it also failed. Then restarted and while loading countdown for boot i hit enter then it went successful boot.

Comment: Unbelievable... , but hit enter works!